# Function guard syntax in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, functional-programming

```
fib::Int->Int
fib n
    n==0        = 1
    n>1     = error "Invalid Number"
```

this function gives me a error

```
Syntax error in declaration (unexpected symbol "==")
```

im not sure whats wrong with the function when compare to the reading material it looks the same

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're missing some of the syntax:

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib n 
    | n == 0  = 1
    | n > 1   = error "Invalid Number"
```

This can also be written without the first newline:

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib n | n == 0  = 1
      | n > 1   = error "Invalid Number"
```

This function is more naturally expressed with [pattern matching:](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions)

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 1
fib n | n > 1 = error "Invalid number"
```

and you might be interested in [the catalogue of fibonaccis](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence#Naive_definition).

Comment: thanks got it i thought `|` was a indicator to show indentation !